# Returning from hospital on Shabbos if it is beyond the Techum

Tags: halacha, shabbat, techum

In this question: [Returning after driving someone to the hospital on Shabbat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/returning-after-driving-someone-to-the-hospital-on-shabbat) the questioner asked whether on may go back home by car on Shabbos after taking someone to the hospital. The accepted answer seems to only answer regarding a Hatzala member.

My question is if a private individual may walk back from the hospital if he will violate Techum Shabbos?

Comment: Driving involves tens of thousands potential *issurei Shabbos* (See Ribiat on driving) .....if you could drive, why *wouldn't* you  be able to leave the Techum?

Comment: @Shokhet: Driving does not have to be done by the person returning. Perhaps a non Jew is driving the person home?

Comment: The halacha is that the person is allowed to drive himself home. .....I didn't (yet) read the halacha you linked to, but that is the halacha.

Comment: @Shokhet: Please read the answers in the question I linked. Rabbi Moshe Feinstein allowed Hatzala members to drive by themselves to return. I do not know if he allowed a private individual to return. Others held only through a non Jew. I do not know that the Halacha is that an individual may drive back himself. Would appreciate a source for such a contention.

Comment: I have one anecdotal p'sak that my father received (even though he didn't drive back that Shabbos), but I don't know what that's worth to you....I'll take a look at that question now.

Comment: So the accepted answer there said that R' Moshe said he could go back, so he's prepared to take the next call...if your person needs to be available for the next call, then walk back. According to R' SZ in that answer, you *wouldn't* be able to, because only *derabonon*s are allowed. Given that answer, what's your question? ....according to R' Moshe, *allowed*, according to R' SZ, *forbidden*.

Comment: @Shokhet: Your father's Psak was for his individual circumstances. Perhaps there were young kids at home with no one to watch them. Perhaps there were other extenuating issues. It is valuable to me if you give the complete question background and the Halachic authority that permitted it.

Comment: @Shokhet: There the discussion is regarding a Hatzala member not a private individual.

Comment: I don't remember who gave that p'sak (though it was someone relatively big), because I wasn't there. There weren't many extenuating circumstances that I remember; my mother was home, and none of us were that young at the time.

Comment: Like I said in an earlier comment; "if your person needs to be available for the next call...."

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect Techum is different from any other prohibition?